# pandas dataframe: divide and replace

Tags: python, pandas

### Background

I am using JupyterLab and Anaconda.

I have 2 similar dataframes. I want to divide (part/subset of) one dataframe by (part/subset of) and then update the original dataframe. Following is the code I have written:

### Code written

```
def f_test_df(n_rows, n_cols):
    df_local = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(n_rows, n_cols))
    df = df_local.applymap(lambda x: round(x*10))
    return df 

np.random.seed(seed=1)

df1 = f_test_df(4, 4)
df1.rename(columns={0:'test'}, inplace=True)
df2 = f_test_df(4, 4)
df2.rename(columns={0:'test'}, inplace=True)
df_div = df1.iloc[:, 1:].div(df2.iloc[:, 1:])
minimum_value = 2
display(df1)
```

[image: df1]

```
display(df2)
```

[image: df2]

```
display(df_div)
```

[image: df_div]

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:].replace(df_div, inplace=True)
df1
```

[image: df1 updated - no change in df1, even after update]

### Desired outcome

I want the df1 to be updated by the obtained division (df_div). As seen from the output, the df1 does not get updated. How should I correct the division process?

Comment: Please post a sample of both dataframes with expected output for better clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the cimpliest is assign back:

```
df1.iloc[:, 1:]  = df1.iloc[:, 1:].div(df2.iloc[:, 1:])

print(df1)
   test         1         2         3
0     4  1.166667  0.000000  1.500000
1     1  0.100000  0.666667  0.428571
2     4  0.555556  4.000000       inf
3     2  1.000000  0.000000  1.750000
```

Comment: Hi, can someone please elaborate why replace does not work, even with 'inplace=True'

Comment: @NeerajHanumante - I think because [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) input values are `str, regex, list, dict, Series, int, float, or None`, so not `DataFrame`